# How to pick up data thru customized rule in tensor flow?

Tags: queue, tensorflow

I am writing to ask how to compose training data based on customized rule. Currently, I am using queue and tf.train.shuffle_batch to retrieve batch of training data. But I want to add some customized logic into the "shuffle" buffer.

Assume my batch size is 128, I want to get data of N different labels, and each has M samples. So, N * M = 128. Yes, my total label count is far more than N. Without this logic, my batch seldomly has samples with the same label, which is bad for my model.

Is there any approach to achieve this logic without writing my own shuffle_batch2 , or prepare data in such order then switch to use batch instead of shuffle_batch?

any help is appreciated!!